# Transferring data from one view to another in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I am new to Rails and am making an e-commerce website.
This is what the code for my view is like (this is a part of the code and not the whole thing):-

```
<% @thriller.each do |book|%>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
    <div class="caption">
      <h4 class="pull-right"><%=book.mrp%></h4>
      <h4><a href="#"><%=book.book_name%></a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <p>No. of pages:<%=book.pages%></p>
    <br>
    <p>In stock:<%=book.stock %></p>
    <br>
    <p>Synopsis:<%=book.synopsis %></p>
    <br>
    <p>Author:<%=book.author %></p>
    <br>
    <p>Publisher:<%=book.publisher %></p>
    <br>
    <p>Genre:<%=book.genre_name%></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="ratings">
      <p>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
  <% @classic.each do|book|%>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4 class="pull-right"><%=book.mrp%></h4>
        <h4><a href="#"><%=book.book_name%></a></h4>
      </div>
      <p>No. of pages:<%=book.pages%></p>
      <br>
      <p>In stock:<%=book.stock %></p>
      <br>
      <p>Synopsis:<%=book.synopsis %></p>
      <br>
      <p>Author:<%=book.author %></p>
      <br>
      <p>Publisher:<%=book.publisher %></p>
      <br>
      <p>Genre:<%=book.genre_name%></p>
      <br>
      <br>
        <div class="ratings">
          <p>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
          </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The controller for this has the following code:-

```
class ShopController < ApplicationController
  def accessories
    @ntbk=Notebook.all
    @bkmk=Bookmark.all
  end

  def books
    @thriller=Book.where(genre_id:1)
    @classic=Book.where(genre_id:2)
    @romance=Book.where(genre_id:3)
    @selfhelp=Book.where(genre_id:4)
    @autob=Book.where(genre_id:5)
  end
end
```

I want the user to be able to click a button and be redirected to a page which displays the details of that particular item. How should I go about doing so?

Console log:-

```
Processing by ShopController#view as 
  Book Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."book_id" IS NULL LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering shop/view.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered shop/view.html.erb within layouts/application (5.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <% @book.each do|book|%>
    2: <p>Name:<%=@book.book_name%></p>
    3: <br>
    4: <p>No. of pages:<%=@book.pages%></p>

app/views/shop/view.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shop_view_html_erb__1842756845584902456_69979582064500'
  Rendering /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (4.7ms)
  Rendering /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendering /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (23.0ms)
```

Comment: Search for 'link_to' tag and how to use it.

Comment: Also read about model resources routes, which provides you with 7 default crud requests commonly used. HINT: you will get your answer there.

Comment: The view you posted is of index action?

Comment: @HarryBomrah yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your above mentioned code part with:

```
<% @thriller.each do |book|%>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
    <div class="caption">
      <h4 class="pull-right"><%=book.mrp%></h4>
      <h4><%=link_to book.book_name, book_path(book.id)%>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <p>No. of pages:<%=book.pages%></p>
    <br>
    <p>In stock:<%=book.stock %></p>
    <br>
    <p>Synopsis:<%=book.synopsis %></p>
    <br>
    <p>Author:<%=book.author %></p>
    <br>
    <p>Publisher:<%=book.publisher %></p>
    <br>
    <p>Genre:<%=book.genre_name%></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="ratings">
      <p>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
  <% @classic.each do|book|%>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4 class="pull-right"><%=book.mrp%></h4>
        <h4><%=link_to book.book_name, book_path(book.id)%></h4>
      </div>
      <p>No. of pages:<%=book.pages%></p>
      <br>
      <p>In stock:<%=book.stock %></p>
      <br>
      <p>Synopsis:<%=book.synopsis %></p>
      <br>
      <p>Author:<%=book.author %></p>
      <br>
      <p>Publisher:<%=book.publisher %></p>
      <br>
      <p>Genre:<%=book.genre_name%></p>
      <br>
      <br>
        <div class="ratings">
          <p>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
          </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And if you don't have `show` action in your `BooksController` then make it with following code:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @book=Book.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

and if you write above code then you have to make a view named as `show.html.erb` in your `views/books` folder with following code.

```
<p>Name:<%=@book.book_name%></p>
<br>
<p>No. of pages:<%=@book.pages%></p>
<br>
<p>In stock:<%=@book.stock %></p>
<br>
<p>Synopsis:<%=@book.synopsis %></p>
<br>
<p>Author:<%=@book.author %></p>
<br>
<p>Publisher:<%=@book.publisher %></p>
<br>
<p>Genre:<%=@book.genre_name%></p>
<br>
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot. Secondly, there is this error: `Couldn't find Book with 'id'= `

Comment: can you show me the server logs from your terminal/command prompt?

Comment: Yeah sure. I've posted it in the original question!

Comment: first of all, you need to remove line#1 `<% @book.each do|book|%>` and may be you have `<%end%>` as your last line(remove that too)

Comment: go to new terminal. and enter command `rails c` and then run command `Book.first` and share the output

Comment: `Book.first
  Book Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" ORDER BY "books"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Book id: 1, book_name: "The Girl on the Train", cart_unit: 0, product_id: 1, pages: 395, stock: 50, synopsis: "Commuter Rachel Watson catches daily glimpses of a...", mrp: 500, author: "Paula Hawkins", publisher: "Riverhead Books", rating: 4, genre_name: "Thriller", book_id: 1001, genre_id: 1, discount: 0, created_at: "2017-04-28 17:15:26", updated_at: "2017-04-28 17:15:26">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143204/discussion-between-g-b-and-sindhugauri).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<%= link_to book.book_name, shop_path(book) %>
```

This will work only in case if your `show` method is in `shop_controller.rb`.

Comment: It's not working. I'm getting the error: `undefined method book_name for nil:NilClass`

Comment: sorry, its not `@book` only `book` as it is in the loop. I have updated the code.

Comment: Okay and how should I be making the other view. The one to which the details are being transferred? I basically want to be able to show all the data being displayed.

Comment: It is better you read a tutorial as it is very detailed and I can't explain the whole thing here. Please read a tutorial and if you 've doubts then you can ask here.